# Windows API which raises exceptions

Tags: c, winapi, exception

I was looking for a classification of winapi functions that may (in one or more scenarios) to throw/raise an exception. an obvious example to that will be CloseHandle on an already closed resource.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: `CloseHandle` doesn't throw exceptions in the C++ sense. It works with the debugger. Is that the classification you're looking for?

Comment: By "exception" do you mean like C++ Exception? Not a single one of the Windows API's are C++ functions, so won't throw exceptions!

Comment: Windows API is C, they do not/can not throw exceptions.

Comment: no I meant SEH, the kind that RaiseException generates. (c++ tag was removed)

Comment: It is not an obvious example, CloseHandle only raises an SEH when you have a debugger attached.  Trying to remind you that your code is vulnerable to handle recycle attacks.  The Win32 api layer doesn't raise exceptions.  But does not go out its way to prevent them either, you'll get slapped with an SEH when you call an api function with a bad pointer value.  The same way your own code would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Win32 API functions are documented as throwing some exceptions (SEH exceptions of course, not C++ exceptions). You can just go to MSDN and check for each function. But I'm not sure it's **entirely** documented, given the quality of Win32 API documentation. This ain't .NET :)

Comment: well yeah, I know.. I was hoping there's a solid classification of these functions.. thanks.

Comment: @user1610015, can you give an example of Win32 API where throwing SEH is documented in a regular use ?

Comment: @JPBlanc HeapAlloc is documented as throwing exceptions (but only if you specify the HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS flag in the second parameter).

Answer (score 0):

There is no single official list of Windows API functions that details which ones raise SEH exceptions. You need to check each and every function that you call.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I worried about api functions that throws exceptions without a clear documentation on the MSDN, but it doesn't seem like there's an answer to that..

Comment: Um, by definition there is no documentation for undocumented behavior.